# Деление в интервале

Tags: python, while

Всем привет!

Надо создать программу, которая будет считать все цифры в интервале(в определённом интервале, которую будет  вводить пользователь, следовательно еще нужен `input()`), которые будут делится на 4. Потом надо будет посчитать сумму эти чисел в интервале, которые делятся на 4. И  также важно было чтобы программа проверяла, делится ли число на 4 без остатка.( с остатком не годится).

Обязательно нужно иcпользовать функцию `def`, `if statement` и `(while loop)`.

Пока мой код выглядит так:

````
    x = int(input("Ievadi pirmo skaitli"))
    y = int(input("Ievadi otro skaitli"))
    while (x != y):
        if (x % 4 > 0):
            x = x + 1
        else:
            a = x```
````

Comment: попробуйте перечитать условие, которое вы написали и переписать на русском, пожалуйста

Comment: @Danis, не работает

Comment: @Zhihar Что именно не понятно в моём сообщении?

Comment: кто там про len писал? поменяйте на sum

Comment: `sum(a in range(x, y+1) if a % 4 == 0); def foo:if(True):while(False):pass;`?

Comment: судя по while (x != y),  range(x, y)

Comment: Ничего не работает

Comment: `все цифры в интервале` - цифры - это такие вещи от 0 до 9, вы имеете в виду цифры или числа все таки?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу (а я не уверен, что понял правильно), то

1. пользователь должен ввести минимальное и максимальное число (диапазон)
2. в указанном диапазоне выбираются числа, которые кратны 4
3. вычисляется сумма данных чисел

Если так, кроме того еще требуется использовать `while`, `if` и `def`, то код может выглядеть так:

```
def calc_sum(left, right):
    res = 0

    value = left

    while value <= right:

        if value % 4 == 0:
            res += value

        value += 1

    return res


left = int(input('введите левую часть диапазона: '))
right = int(input('введите правую часть диапазона: '))

print("результат:", calc_sum(left, right))
```

или все таки надо подсчитать сумму цифр чисел, кратных 4?

**P.S.**

чтобы вводить границы не диапазона в одном запросе, а не в двух, можно сделать такой код:

```
def calc_sum(borders):
    res = 0

    value = borders[0]

    while value <= borders[1]:

        if value % 4 == 0:
            res += value

        value += 1

    return res


borders = list(map(int, input('введите диапазон: ').split()))

print("результат:", calc_sum(borders))
```

тогда ввести можно сразу

```
10 20
```

А вообще эта задача может быть решена в 1 строку

```
borders = list(map(int, input('введите диапазон: ').split()))

res = sum([i for i in range(borders[0], borders[1] + 1) if i % 4 == 0])

print("результат:", res)
```

Однако если разговор все таки шел о подсчёте суммы цифр в числах, кратных 4, то тогда можно использовать функцию:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    res = 0

    value = abs(num)

    while value > 0:
        res += value % 10
        value //= 10

    return res
```